# Передача картинок из массива на др экран

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Не меняется картинка при отображении всех картинок
Передаю картинки с первого экрана

```
let exersiseImage = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   let exersiseViewController2: WorkoutStandingViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! WorkoutStandingViewController
   exersiseViewController2.exersiseImage = exersiseImage
```

На др контроллере принимаю

```
var exersiseImage = []
var imageEx = UIImageView()

//Во вьюдидлоаде
var imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
imageView = imageEx
imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "\(exersiseImage[0])"))//первая картинка
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width/1.8, height: self.view.bounds.width/1.8)
imageView.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: self.view.bounds.height/2.9)
view.addSubview(imageView)`
```

Далее при смене значения i отображаем последующие картинки из массива

```
//Не во вьюдидлоаде 
var i = 0
if...{//какое-то условие c учетом увеличения i+=1
   imageEx.image = UIImage(named: "\(exersiseImage[i])")
}
```

НО КАРТИНКА НЕ МЕНЯЕТСЯ, ОСТАЕТСЯ ПЕРВАЯ КАРТИНКА ИЗ МАССИВА, КАК ИСПРАВИТЬ? СПАСИБО

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выполняй это код в методе viewWillAppear. И не забудь сделать imageView полем класса.

```
var i = 0 if...{//какое-то условие c учетом увеличения i+=1   
    imageEx.image = UIImage(named: "\(exersiseImage[i])")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Зачем тройная инициализация?

Вынесите свой `imageView` в поле класса:

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
```

Во `viewDidLoad`:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(exersiseImage[0])"))
```

И затем меняйте картинку (если из главного, можете без gcd):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(exersiseImage[i])")
})
```